# How to get the axis value with respect to the cross hair in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

I'm working with x-range type of highcharts for a timeline, is there any way to get the axis value where the cross hair / mouse is hovered.

in this pic the cross hair is between a particular time duration [image] but the tooltip is showing the points, is there any way to show the current hovered axis point on the tooltip ?

i have added code link is on the comment, thanks in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F4e2Y/189/ code link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to find the exact position , need to use highstock for that , thanks for @ppotaczek because of his answer which helped me to find some exact solution for this is in comment ,( sorry dunno how to link the jsfiddle link, shows error for indent spacing when submitting the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts tooltip is based on series points and changing the way it works would require a lot of customization. To workaround, you can add transparent dummy `line` series and dispable `enableMouseTracking` option in `xrange` series. Please look at the example below:

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var newSeries = this.series[1],
                min = this.xAxis[0].min,
                max = this.xAxis[0].max,
                data = [],
                i,
                time = 60 * 1000;

            for (i = min; i < max; i += time) {
                data.push({
                    x: i,
                    y: 0
                })
            }
            newSeries.setData(data);
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aekvnf4d/

Comment: thank you @ppotaczek , but is there any way to access this.series[0].data,
`{
            x: 1539001765000,
            x2: 1539003025000,
            y: 0,
      } `


 when i console 'this' i can't find these values, i'm seeing only the values which you marked on the line type graph

Comment: Hi Vigneshwaran N, you can access to the first series data by: `this.series.chart.series[0].points`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t8kmxzj3/

Comment: hi @ppotaczek , yeah but it's display the entire points, consider if a click is made on the blue bar ,is there any way to get that x,x2 alone where the user clicked http://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/t8kmxzj3/1/ i'm also looking for some ways to get that, if you have any ideas please suggest me, thank you so much !

Comment: is there any way to add hover effect on that blue bar if you hover a particular time in line , both the line & x-range are intersect can't apply click event for that xrange, can anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hi Vigneshwaran N, There is a problem (probably a bug) with `hover` state in `xrange` series type. As a workaround I used asynchronous code, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5rwat9z2/